# How to get HP ASM to work under Xen Hypervisor?

Tags: hardware, xen, hp, hp-proliant

I have a HP DL560, currently running Debian Squeeze as dom0 on Xen Hypervisor, and the fans constantly run at 100%. In the past this wasn't a problem because I could install HP's ASM which includes fan management. However since I have installed a xen enabled kernel, the hp-health driver (the piece of ASM that controls the fans) won't start (at boot or manually). Anyone know of any way to make it work? (Or any other method of controlling the fans safely.)

Note that the server has four i386 Xeon CPUs, each with its own fan, plus an extra case fan, and all of the fans can be doubled for redundancy. Also everything works fine under Squeeze without the xen-enabled kernel (can still boot the other one and hp-health loads fine on boot).

Answer (score 1):

Scary... I own an [HP ProLiant DL560 G1](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11595_ca/11595_ca.HTML). It's sitting somewhere. It's very old gear... 2U, 4-socket Pentium 4-era server with two drive bays :) Mine dates back to 2004.

Either way, its fans *do* respond to the HP health drivers. You mention `hpasm`. That's an old health driver model. For the past few years, the HP drivers have been packaged as `hp-snmp-agents`. Try downloading the [HP Debian/dpkg driver bundle](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_c45bd2c25e6849d19f98427649%257CswEnvOID%253D4123%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

The goal here is that the drivers will compile against your running kernel. The fact that you're on a Xen-enabled kernel should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it despite their name change, installing `hpasm` (from HP's repository) actually installs `hp-snmp-agents 8.7.0` (which is what is contained in the ISO on the link you sent). As a result it appears that the xen kernel does seem to have an impact on the driver...

The output of `/etc/init.d/hp-health start`:

```
root@dom0:~# /etc/init.d/hp-health start
 Starting Proliant System Health Monitor (hpasmd): 
            [ SUCCESS ]

root@dom0:~# 
Message from syslogd@dom0 at Nov 20 21:41:58 ...
 kernel:[ 1572.521828] general protection fault: 0000 [#3] SMP 

Message from syslogd@dom0 at Nov 20 21:41:58 ...
 kernel:[ 1572.522086] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/pci0000:03/0000:03:01.2/class

Message from syslogd@dom0 at Nov 20 21:41:58 ...
 kernel:[ 1572.525785] Process hpasmd (pid: 5981, ti=ec11a000 task=c1ce0880 task.ti=ec11a000)

Message from syslogd@dom0 at Nov 20 21:41:58 ...
 kernel:[ 1572.525785] Stack:

Message from syslogd@dom0 at Nov 20 21:41:58 ...
 kernel:[ 1572.525785] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@dom0 at Nov 20 21:41:58 ...
 kernel:[ 1572.525785] Code: 00 8d 76 00 f7 44 24 08 00 00 02 80 75 33 50 b8 00 e0 ff ff 21 e0 8b 40 10 8b 04 85 d0 c2 3f c1 8b 80 0c b0 45 c1 f6 44 24 0d 02 <0f> 94 40 01 66 83 38 01 75 04 c6 40 01 01 58 0f 84 44 33 00 00 

Message from syslogd@dom0 at Nov 20 21:41:58 ...
 kernel:[ 1572.525785] EIP: [<c10067bf>] xen_iret+0x27/0x2b SS:ESP 0069:ec11bfe0
```

Followed by `hpasmcli`:

```
root@dom0:~# hpasmcli

ERROR: Could not open /dev/cpqhealth/cdt.
Please make sure the Health Monitor is started.
```

(This should probably be a comment, but I am not allowed to post comments.)